# Search with time range in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I find records from `4 am` the current day to `4 am` the next day. The difficult part is if it is `2 am` I am looking for records from `4 am` the previous day to `4 am` the current day. And at `4:01 am` I am looking for records from `4 am` the current day to `4 am` the next day.

Can this be done?

```
start_time = 4AM
end_time = 4AM
found_attendance_record = Volunteer::Attendance.where(volunteer_id: params[:id], in: start_time..end_time))`
```

Comment: Seems like you got it basically... what is the issue really here?

Comment: The part that won't work is when it is midnight, the day changes. How can I change it to start the day before? Before midnight, 4am is the same day and after midnight 4am is the previous day. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want find records from 4am the current day to 4am the next day, simply do like bellow:

```
start_time = Date.today.to_time + 4.hours
end_time = start_time + 1.day

found_attendance_record = Volunteer::Attendance.where(volunteer_id: params[:id], your_datetime_column: start_time..end_time)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works. I still don't know how I will solve the problem from midnight to 4am the next day, but I think I will just create a different query for it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean from midnight of today to 4am of next day( a range of 28 hours) or midnight of tomorrow to 4am of tomorrow( a range of 4 hours)?

Comment: I mean midnight of tomorrow to 4am of tomorrow( a range of 4 hours). Because if I run your code at 2am, it will be querying for 4am that day to 4am the next day, when it should be from 4am the previous day. I think I will stick with using this if it is past midnight but before 4 am. `start_time = Date.yesturday.to_time + 4.hours` `end_time = start_time + 1.day`

Answer (score 0):

```
t1=DateTime.now.in_time_zone('UTC').change({hour:4, min:0, sec:0})
t2=t1 + 24.hours
found_attendance_record = Volunteer::Attendance.where(created_at: t1..t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, try the following

Create hour

```
 start_time = "04:00:00"
 start_time = start_time.to_time
 #=> 2018-02-06 04:00:00 +0000  # it's showing current date 4 AM
```

Now you can plus 24 hours

```
end_time = start_time + 24.hours
#=>  2018-02-07 04:00:00 +0000 # it's showing plus one day 4 am
```

Now you can start query

```
found_attendance_record = Volunteer::Attendance.where(volunteer_id: params[:id], in: start_time..end_time))
```

Hope it helps